# Using Fluent nHibernate with VS2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, fluent-nhibernate

I have not been able to find any definitive answers to this question:

Can Fluent nHibernate be used with VS2005?  All the examples on fluentnhibernate.org seem to use c# 3 syntax (lambdas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Fluent NHibernerate takes advantage of many of the .NET 3.5 additions like Actions.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  My company won't let us use VS2008 because it would cost $$$ to renew our msdn subscriptions, so for now we're stuck on VS2005.  Thanks.

Comment: @Chris: You might check if the express editions of VS2008 will cover your needs for now.  It has a few limits like not allowing mixed project types in a solution.  But are least you can get LINQ and .Net 3.5 for free.

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear. While I understand their prespective that our software is expensive it's not really acceptable for a company at this point to still refuse to even be on 2008. We're nearing the dawn of 4.0 to be that far behind is a huge liability and the hidden costs they pay in lost productivity and lost tool usage will easily cost them many times over the fixed cost of upgrading software IMO.